# how to make Google Map info windows immediately show after load the map in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I can show Google Map on my Flutter app by using the code below

```
        final marker = Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId("someID"),
          position: LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "Venue Name"),
        );

         GoogleMap(
            onTap: (newCoordinate) => onMapTapped(newCoordinate, controller),
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            onMapCreated: onGoogleMapCreated,
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(0.0, 0,0),
              zoom: 15.0,
            ),
            markers: {marker},
          ),
```

to show the info window, I need to tap that red marker first. what I want is ....

whenever the map load in the screen, that info window will immediately open without I need to tap the red marker. so I can show that "Venue Name" . how to do that?

Comment: You can use [showMarkerInfoWindow](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMapController/showMarkerInfoWindow.html) method to programatically show the Info Window for a marker

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to Nelson Jr to give a clue, I can solve it by using this code `showMarkerInfoWindow` method from Google Map Controller. please see the `onMapCreated` property below

```
          GoogleMap(
            onTap: (newCoordinate) {},
            onMapCreated: (mapController) {
  
             mapController.showMarkerInfoWindow(MarkerId("yourMarkerIdHere"));

            },
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
              zoom: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: you wanted to show infoWindow for only one Marker? Any idea to show info window on many markers at same time?